# How do I send a guid via hotstring?

Tags: autohotkey

I am using

```
:*:\guid::
 send_guid() {
    TypeLib := ComObjCreate("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
    NewGUID := TypeLib.Guid
    send, %NewGUID%
}
```

I know the guid is generated because I can put MsgBox, %NewGUID% and the Guid is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the {text} mode like so:

```
send, {text}%NewGUID%
```

Because the GUID starts with { which has a special meaning in the Send command.

See https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm#Text